# How i get Value from HashMap?

Tags: java, javascript

First sry for my english I'm from germany.

I have a hashmap like this:

```
private Map<Integer, IMessageEvent> messages;
```

I send event messages with javascript to my server.
This is my handle:

```
public void handleMessage(Session session, MessageEvent event) {
    if (this.messages.containsKey(event.id)) {
        Logging.writeLog("Message received [" + event.id + "] " + event.msg + " (HANDLING)");
        this.messages.get(event.id).parse(session, event);
    } else  {
        Logging.writeLog("Message received [" + event.id + "] " + event.msg);
    }
}
```

Log:

> LOG: Message received [2] @B@C**X1X**@E**hd-g1** (HANDLING)

How i can get the X1X?
I`ll get the userid. I send like this:

```
        var composer = MessageComposer(2);
        composer.pushString("X1X");
        composer.pushString("hd-g1");
        game.serverMessage(composer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
event.readString()
```

I'`ve looked in the Event Class and saw the readString function.